# Books Regarding Flash Media Server development

Tags: apache-flex, flash, media

What is the best book out there reagrding Flash Media Server development using flex 4/ Action script. There are many books or resources out there on Flex and action script but nothing specialized on Flash Media Server.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find any good definitive guides out there.... I usually end up going and looking at the developer blogs of the Adobe staff at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/

Sorry.. not the answer you were looking for.